# How to store list of files and folder in list or set using java?

Tags: java, file-io, file-handling

I have return code to retrieve a list of all filepaths within a directory but I'm only getting the contents of the last folder. I have two folders, each has 3 files.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Filedirexts 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String Dirpath = "E:/Share/tstlpatches";
        String fieldirpath ="";
        File file = new File(Dirpath);
        List<String> strfilelst = new ArrayList<String>();
        strfilelst = Filedirexts.getsubdir(file);
        System.out.println(strfilelst.size());

        for(int i=0;i<strfilelst.size();i++)
        {
            fieldirpath = strfilelst.get(i);
            System.out.println("fieldirpath : "+fieldirpath);
        }
    }

    public static List<String> getsubdir(File file) throws IOException
    {
        File[] filelist = file.listFiles();
        List<String> strfileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("filelist" + filelist.length);

        for (int i=0; i< filelist.length ; i++)
        {
            if(filelist[i].exists())
            {
                if(filelist[i].isFile())
                {
                    file = filelist[i];
                    System.out.println( " fileeach file : "+fileeach.getAbsolutePath());
                    strfileList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
                else if (filelist[i].isDirectory())
                {
                    file = filelist[i];
                    System.out.println( " fileeach Directory : "+fileeach.getCanonicalPath());
                    strfileList = Filedirexts.getsubdir(file);
                    strfileList.add(file.getCanonicalPath().toString());
                }
            }
        }
        return strfileList;
    }
}
```

This is my folder structure:
MainPath **E:\Share\tstlpatches** which is used in code itself

```
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE 
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\graphical
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\graphical\data1.txt
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\graphical\data2.txt
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\graphical\data3.txt
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\test 
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\test\1.txt
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\test\2.txt
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\test\readme.txt
```

I'm only getting

```
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE 
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\test
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\test\1.txt 
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\test\2.txt
E:\Share\tstlpatches\BE\test\readme.txt
```

If I use the normal method, it works fine, but when I use with the list I'm only getting the constents of the last folder.

What do I need to do to make the code work properly?

Comment: `strfileList = Filedirexts.getsubdir(file);` is overwriting the entire previous value what you want here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive method is incorrectly creating a new `ArrayList<String>` in each call and returning this new `ArrayList` in each invocation. This is why you are only seeing the contents of the last call.

Here's how to fix this:

1) Change the `getsubdir` to be void and pass in the List as a parameter.

```
public static void getsubdir(File file, List<String> strfileList) throws IOException
{
    File[] filelist = file.listFiles();
    System.out.println("filelist " + filelist.length);

    for (int i=0; i< filelist.length ; i++)
    {
        if(filelist[i].exists())
        {
            if(filelist[i].isFile())
            {
                file = filelist[i];
                System.out.println( " fileeach file : "+file.getAbsolutePath());
                strfileList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            else if (filelist[i].isDirectory())
            {
                file = filelist[i];
                System.out.println( " fileeach Directory : "+file.getCanonicalPath());

                // Note: Since you want the directory first in the list, 
                // add it before the recursive call
                strfileList.add(file.getCanonicalPath().toString());
                Filedirexts.getsubdir(file, strfileList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) Change the way you call it from main:

Instead of:

```
strfilelst = Filedirexts.getsubdir(file);
```

Just use:

```
Filedirexts.getsubdir(file, strfilelst);
```

Comment: yeah..!! Thanks Buddy.. It's working fine. :) listed out all subfolders and it's file.